# Flex align baseline content to input with label

Tags: html, css, flexbox

We currently have an input that we want to align baseline to the content around it.  The label wrappers the input and for the most part everything aligns correctly.  However we have been wanting to pull the input outside the label, but this seems to be throwing the layout off.

This snippet demonstrates the issue and possible solutions. However, I want to know is there a better option? Or a way to get the label to be ignored by the baseline layout?

```html
<h1>Original <span style="font-size: 14px;">(input within label)</span></h1>
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; align-items: baseline; gap: 8px;">
  <div>Test value</div>
  <div>
    <label for="myInput" style="display: inline-block;">
      <div>My label</div>
      <input id="myInput" placeholder="test" />
    </label>
  </div>
  <button>My Button</button>
</div>

<h1>Problem <span style="font-size: 14px;">(splitting label and input breaks layout)</span></h1>
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; align-items: baseline; gap: 8px;">
  <div>Test value</div>
  <div>
    <label for="myInput" style="display: block;">My label</label>
    <input id="myInput" placeholder="test" />
  </div>
  <button>My Button</button>
</div>

<h1>Option 1 <span style="font-size: 14px;">(absolute position the label)</span></h1>
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; align-items: baseline; gap: 8px;">
  <div>Test value</div>
  <div style="position: relative;">
    <label for="myInput" style="position: absolute;">My label</label>
    <input id="myInput" placeholder="test" style="margin-top: 1rem"/>
  </div>
  <button>My Button</button>
</div>

<h1>Option 2 <span style="font-size: 14px;">(float label, but label is outside container)</span></h1>
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; align-items: baseline; gap: 8px;">
  <div>Test value</div>
  <div>
    <label for="myInput" style="position: absolute; transform: translateY(-1rem);">My label</label>
    <input id="myInput" placeholder="test"/>
  </div>
  <button>My Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of "baseline", use "last baseline"

```html
<h1>Original <span style="font-size: 14px;">(input within label)</span></h1>
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; align-items: baseline; gap: 8px;">
  <div>Test value</div>
  <div>
    <label for="myInput" style="display: inline-block;">
      <div>My label</div>
      <input id="myInput" placeholder="test" />
    </label>
  </div>
  <button>My Button</button>
</div>

<h1>Problem <span style="font-size: 14px;">(splitting label and input breaks layout)</span></h1>
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; align-items: baseline; gap: 8px;">
  <div>Test value</div>
  <div>
    <label for="myInput" style="display: block;">My label</label>
    <input id="myInput" placeholder="test" />
  </div>
  <button>My Button</button>
</div>

<h1>Option 1 <span style="font-size: 14px;">(absolute position the label)</span></h1>
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; align-items: baseline; gap: 8px;">
  <div>Test value</div>
  <div style="position: relative;">
    <label for="myInput" style="position: absolute;">My label</label>
    <input id="myInput" placeholder="test" style="margin-top: 1rem"/>
  </div>
  <button>My Button</button>
</div>

<h1>Option 2 <span style="font-size: 14px;">(float label, but label is outside container)</span></h1>
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; align-items: baseline; gap: 8px;">
  <div>Test value</div>
  <div>
    <label for="myInput" style="position: absolute; transform: translateY(-1rem);">My label</label>
    <input id="myInput" placeholder="test"/>
  </div>
  <button>My Button</button>
</div>

<h1>Last baseline <span style="font-size: 14px;">(splitting label and input)</span></h1>
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; align-items: last baseline; gap: 8px;">
  <div>Test value</div>
  <div>
    <label for="myInput" style="display: block;">My label</label>
    <input id="myInput" placeholder="test" />
  </div>
  <button>My Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I’ve learned something new today, thanks!

Comment: Same here never new of last baseline.  Do you happen to know if tailwind has a helper for it?

Comment: @Tim.Burnell It doesn't look like it. I think you'd have to add it to the tailwind config. But I'm not a tailwind user.

Comment: I liked this answer the best so far, but it was just pointed out to me that if there is hint text ... it will align to the hint text.

Comment: That may well be true, but your question doesn't have hint text, so that's out of scope :-). There may be a tricksier way of achieving what you need with hint text, but it's probably best if you create a new question with appropriate examples with hint text so we can address that separately.

Comment: Here if you want to look at the other post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77462121/aligning-inputs-in-a-row

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is a better option: a grid. Grids support `align-items: baseline`, which will achieve the layout you want.

```css
body, input, button {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.d1 {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  align-items: baseline;
  gap: 5px 1em;
}

.d2 {
  grid-row: 2;
}

.d3 {
  display: contents;
}

.d3>label {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.d3>input {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.d1>button {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
  <div class="d2">Test value</div>
  <div class="d3">
    <label for="myInput" style="display: block;">My label</label>
    <input id="myInput" placeholder="test" />
  </div>
  <button>My Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes this works, however I am making an Angular component that is the input ... so it will have a wrapping container around the label and input will, so the grid will not work the best here. and the two other fields would be adjacent elements.

Comment: You can still use a grid, even with a wrapper element around the label and input, if you style the wrapper with [`display: contents`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#box). This causes the wrapper to effectively disappear from the document hierarchy, allowing the label and input to move up a level to be treated as children of the main grid. I have updated my answer to add the wrapper and style it this way.