# Aligning inputs in a row

Tags: html, css, angular, web-component

this is related to this post: [Flex align baseline content to input with label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77456590/flex-align-baseline-content-to-input-with-label/77457211#77457211)

I have components that will make inputs, and I am trying to find the best way to layout the elements to be in align. I want all the input and buttons to be in a line (having labels above the inputs and hints below the input).

The css is scoped between host and component ... so don't feel like css grid is the best option. I can change styles in the component (but it needs to live inside the component), and i can change the styles outside the component (but don't want it trying to reach in).

```html
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; align-items: baseline; gap: 8px;">
  <div class="myComponent" style="width: 100px">
    <input id="myInput" placeholder="No label" style="width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;"/>
  </div>
  <div class="myComponent"  style="width: 100px">
    <label for="myInput" style="display: block">Hint</label>
    <input id="myInput" placeholder="test" style="width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;"/>
    <small style="display: block">hint</small>
  </div>
  <div class="myComponent"  style="width: 100px">
    <label for="myInput" style="display: block">Long Hint</label>
    <input id="myInput" placeholder="test" style="width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;"/>
    <small style="display: block">A really long hint that wraps</small>
  </div>
  <div class="myComponent"  style="width: 100px">
    <label for="myInput" style="display: block">No Hint</label>
    <input id="myInput" placeholder="test" style="width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;"/>
  </div>
  <button style="text-wrap: nowrap;">My Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by applying `grid-template-rows: subgrid;`.
Here is an example for you:

```css
.my-components {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 100px);
  grid-rows: repeat(3, auto);
  align-items: center;
}

.my-component {
  display: grid;
  grid-row: span 3;
  grid-template-rows: subgrid;
}

.my-component label {
  margin-top: auto;
}

.my-component input {
  width: 100%;
}

.my-component input:first-child,
.my-component button {
  grid-row-start: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-components">
  <div class="my-component">
    <input placeholder="No label">
  </div>
  <div class="my-component">
    <label for="input-1">Hint</label>
    <input id="input-1" placeholder="test">
    <small>hint</small>
  </div>
  <div class="my-component">
    <label for="input-2">Long<br>Hint</label>
    <input id="input-2" placeholder="test">
    <small>A really long hint that wraps</small>
  </div>
  <div class="my-component">
    <label for="input-3">No Hint</label>
    <input id="input-3" placeholder="test">
  </div>
  <div class="my-component">
    <button>My Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

P.S. `id` and `label` `for` must be unique.